# cfコマンドのインストールがmac上で失敗します

Tags: bluemix

Bluemixを使ってローカル環境で作成したアプリをcfコマンドでGit上にプッシュしたいと思い、以下のリンクを参考にインストールを実施しました。
しかしながら、.pkgファイルが開けません。インストール方法をご教示ください。

http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/

Answer (score 0):

メッセージか何か出力されているでしょうか？
まずはMacのセキュリティー設定を確認してください。

Appleメニュー>システム環境設定>セキュリティーとプライバシー>一般タブ

ここでダウンロードしたアプリケーションの実行許可を、すべてのアプリケーションを許可に設定しなおしてインストールを行ってください。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]